# Trac tab-delimited Export

Tags: sql, export, trac, csv

I am trying to export my trac tickets-change history with following SQL-Query

> SELECT DISTINCT
>
> t.id AS Ticket, t.description as Description,
>
> group_concat ( tc.author, '; ') AS Author,
>
> group_concat ( tc.field, '; ') AS Field
>
> /*group_concat ( tc.oldvalue, '; ') AS Comments_Old */
>
> group_concat ( tc.newvalue, '; ') AS Comments_New
>
> FROM ticket t
>
> LEFT JOIN ticket_change tc ON ( t.id=tc.ticket )
>
> GROUP BY t.id, t.summary

Problem is that he puts a linebreak at the field 'Comments_New' like seen on the screenshot

Comment: I Cannot post a screenshot because i haven't got enough points?!! -_-

Comment: What is your aim with exporting the tickets? You may wan to use [ExportImportXlsPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ExportImportXlsPlugin).

Comment: i want to delete the newlines or line breaks because i want to integrate the tickets into another system. i already tried with
`GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(tc.newvalue, '\n', ''), '; ') AS Comments_New`
but it didn't work